# Cannot get acces to file in google drive (Id must be provided)

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am making code based on android google drive demo. I think i've copied all setings propeerly as i can create files and folder and make queries; However when I am tring doenload file I recieve error saing that Id must be provided.

How my code works:
At firs I am making query to get `id's` of files with name i am interested. And get following:

```
04-21 11:36:51.374: D/folder id(6468): DriveId:CAESHDBCdzhlOWswMlprblVNRXN4VUd0Nk5IQXphRmsYhgggmNuW1qxR
04-21 11:36:51.374: D/folder name(6468): gdGatheredText.txt
04-21 11:36:51.374: D/folder id(6468): DriveId:CAESHDBCdzhlOWswMlprblVkamR1VFhwNGNtcG9NbGsY_gcgmNuW1qxR
04-21 11:36:51.374: D/folder name(6468): gdGatheredText.txt
04-21 11:36:51.374: D/folder id(6468): DriveId:CAESHDBCdzhlOWswMlprblVlWE5SWm10T1RXWXhZalEY9AcgmNuW1qxR
04-21 11:36:51.374: D/folder name(6468): gdGatheredText.txt
```

I take the id of the last file `CAESHDBCdzhlOWswMlprblVlWE5SWm10T1RXWXhZalEY9AcgmNuW1qxR` and pass it to uumodefied code from apidemo. My error is fierd at line `DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(),
                    params[0]);`

load class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.ContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveIdResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Filters;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Query;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.SearchableField;

public class GDriveLoadText extends BaseGDriveActivity {
    private String id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onConnected(connectionHint);
        Query query = new Query.Builder()
                .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "plain/text"))
                .addFilter(
                        Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "gdGatheredText.txt"))
                .build();
        Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query).setResultCallback(
                metadataCallback);
    }

    final private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadataCallback = new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Problem while retrieving results");
                finish();
            }
            MetadataBuffer metadata = result.getMetadataBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < metadata.getCount(); i++) {
                Log.d("folder id", metadata.get(i).getDriveId().toString());
                Log.d("folder name", metadata.get(i).getTitle().toString());
            }
            if (metadata.getCount() > 0) {
                String driveId = metadata.get(metadata.getCount() - 1)
                        .getDriveId().toString();
                id =driveId.replace("DriveId:", "");
                Log.d("file id", id);
            }
            metadata.close();
            Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), id)
                    .setResultCallback(idCallback);
        }
    };
    final private ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
            new RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask(
                    GDriveLoadText.this).execute(result.getDriveId());
        }
    };

    final private class RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask extends
            ApiClientAsyncTask<DriveId, Boolean, String> {

        public RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackgroundConnected(DriveId... params) {
            String contents = null;
            DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(),
                    params[0]);
            ContentsResult contentsResult = file.openContents(
                    getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                    .await();
            if (!contentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                return null;
            }
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    contentsResult.getContents().getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                contents = builder.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("download text",
                        "IOException while reading from the stream", e);
            }

            file.discardContents(getGoogleApiClient(),
                    contentsResult.getContents()).await();
            GatheredData.INSTANCE.setGatheredText(contents);
            return contents;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result == null) {
                showMessage("Error while reading from the file");
                return;
            }
            showMessage("File contents: " + result);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

base class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;

/**
 * An abstract activity that handles authorization and connection to the Drive
 * services.
 */
public abstract class BaseGDriveActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "BaseDriveActivity";


    /**
     * Extra for account name.
     */
    protected static final String EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME = "account_name";

    /**
     * Request code for auto Google Play Services error resolution.
     */
    protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;

    /**
     * Next available request code.
     */
    protected static final int NEXT_AVAILABLE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

    /**
     * Google API client.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Called when activity gets visible. A connection to Drive services need to
     * be initiated as soon as the activity is visible. Registers
     * {@code ConnectionCallbacks} and {@code OnConnectionFailedListener} on the
     * activities itself.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    /**
     * Handles resolution callbacks.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when activity gets invisible. Connection to Drive service needs to
     * be disconnected as soon as an activity is invisible.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is connected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is disconnected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is trying to connect but failed.
     * Handle {@code result.getResolution()} if there is a resolution is
     * available.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // show the localized error dialog.
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows a toast message.
     */
    public void showMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the {@code GoogleApiClient}.
     */
    public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
      return mGoogleApiClient;
    }
}
```

error

```
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468): Process: com.example.infoscrapper2, PID: 6468
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Id must be provided.
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.l.getFile(Unknown Source)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at com.example.infoscrapper2.GDriveLoadText$RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask.doInBackgroundConnected(GDriveLoadText.java:84)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at com.example.infoscrapper2.GDriveLoadText$RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask.doInBackgroundConnected(GDriveLoadText.java:1)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at com.example.infoscrapper2.ApiClientAsyncTask.doInBackground(ApiClientAsyncTask.java:63)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-21 11:36:52.295: E/AndroidRuntime(6468):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Are you sure params[0] actually has an ID in it?  Most likely that is null.

Comment: @konopko no. At that time i just switch to java google drive

Comment: @Yarh it seems I solved this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553989/how-to-get-google-drive-file-id#comment39999526_25555159

Comment: i have same problem each time i am getting this? Anyone know why?